# How to Add and Remove Animation RecyclerView's items

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm making a music app. I have a recyclerview and I am playing clicked item's music, at the same time animation works too. Question is whenever user change the recyclerview's item position I need to cancel first animation and start new one for new position. I mean every time will be just 1 animation exist.

**My RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter(private val ModelList:List<Musics>,private val listener: 
ClickListener) :RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>(){



class ViewHolder(var binding:GridListBinding):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val view = DataBindingUtil.inflate<GridListBinding>(inflater,R.layout.grid_list,parent,false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.binding.musics = ModelList[position]


    holder.binding.constraint.setOnClickListener{
        listener.buttonClicked(holder.binding.constraint,ModelList[position],position)
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return ModelList.size
}

}
```

**My ClickListener for adapter**

```
interface ClickListener {
fun buttonClicked(view: View,model: Musics,position:Int)

}
```

**grid_list for recyclerviewAdapter**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>
<data>

    <variable
        name="musics"
        type="com.tunahan.musicplayer.model.Musics" />
    <variable
        name="listener"
        type="com.tunahan.musicplayer.adapter.ClickListener" />

</data>

 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

android:layout_width="125dp"
android:id="@+id/constraint"
android:layout_height="125dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="52dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="42dp"
>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:src="@drawable/musical"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"



    />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gridTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fontFamily="@font/allerta"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:text="@{musics.filename}"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />




   </LinearLayout>


   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   </layout>
```

**And Pulse Animation for gridlist's imageView**

```
       scaleDown = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(
            view.image,
            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 1.1f),
            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 1.1f),
        )
        scaleDown.duration = 500
        scaleDown.repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
        scaleDown.repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.REVERSE

        scaleDown.start()
```

**ClickListener**

```
override fun buttonClicked(view: View, model: Musics, position: Int) {

    path = model.filepath
    nextMusic = position
    positionplus = position
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)

    saveduid = sharedPref.getInt("changed", model.uid)
    editor = sharedPref.edit()
    editor.putInt("changed", model.uid)
    editor.apply()

    editor2.putInt("positionplus", positionplus)
    editor2.apply()





    if (saveduid == model.uid) {

        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
            ForegroundService.startService(
                this, path = path, action = "ACTION_PAUSE",
                positionplus, ModelList[positionplus].filename
            )
            scaleDown.cancel()

            binding.seekbartextend.text = createTimeLabel(mediaPlayer.duration)

            binding.playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_arrow_24)

        } else {
            ForegroundService.startService(
                this, path = path, action = "ACTION_PLAY",
                positionplus,ModelList[positionplus].filename
            )


            binding.seekbartextend.text = createTimeLabel(mediaPlayer.duration)

            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {
                nextButton()
            }

            binding.playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.circledpause)
            runnable = Runnable {
                binding.seekBar.max = mediaPlayer.duration
                binding.seekBar.progress = mediaPlayer.currentPosition
                binding.seekbarTextstart.text = createTimeLabel(mediaPlayer.currentPosition)
                binding.seekbartextend.text = createTimeLabel(mediaPlayer.duration)
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)
            }
            handler.post(runnable)

        }


    } else {


        ForegroundService.startService(
            this, path = path, action = "ACTION_RESET",
            positionplus,ModelList[positionplus].filename
        )
        if (positionplus != position)

        scaleDown = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(
            view.image,
            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 1.1f),
            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 1.1f),
        )
        scaleDown.duration = 500
        scaleDown.repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
        scaleDown.repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.REVERSE

        scaleDown.start()



        binding.seekbartextend.text = createTimeLabel(mediaPlayer.duration)

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {
            nextButton()
        }
        binding.playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.circledpause)
        runnable = Runnable {
            binding.seekBar.max = mediaPlayer.duration
            binding.seekBar.progress = mediaPlayer.currentPosition
            binding.seekbarTextstart.text = createTimeLabel(mediaPlayer.currentPosition)
            binding.seekbartextend.text = createTimeLabel(mediaPlayer.duration)
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)
        }
        handler.post(runnable)
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you trying to cancel your already started animation? Can you also add the code piece where you handle the button click and start the animation, please?

Comment: @EfeBudak I added. For example Recyclerview's item animation which is at position 0 runs when I run buttonClicked() then I'm changing position to 1. Then I want to cancel animation which is at position 0 and then run animation position 1. It's going to show us to which music is playing right now. I hope I could explain.

Comment: The `ObjejtAnimator` class extends `ValueAnimator` class that has an `end()` method call. Can you check the link below and try to end the `scaleDown` animation before starting a new one?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator#end()